# How do you start a memcached session in symfony2?

Tags: php, session, symfony, memcached

I'll try to be as detailed as possible because I was searching for now , 75 hours for a solution ..

Brace yourselves.. here we go :

I'm trying to implement the `MemcacheD` session handler for Symfony2 :
I have downloaded the necessary libraries and then configured Symfony2 as follows:

In `app/config.yml` :

```
imports:
    # ....
    - { resource: services/session.yml }

framework:
    # ....
    session:
      handler_id:     session.handler.memcached
```

`app/config/parameters.yml`:

```
session_memcached_host:     127.0.0.1
session_memcached_port:     11211
session_memcached_prefix:   ng_
session_memcached_expire:   43200
```

`app/services/session.yml` :

```
services:
    session.memcached:
        class: Memcached
        arguments:
            persistent_id: %session_memcached_prefix%
        calls:
            - [ addServer, [ %session_memcached_host%, %session_memcached_port% ]]

    session.handler.memcached:
        class:     Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\MemcachedSessionHandler
        arguments: [@session.memcached, { prefix: %session_memcached_prefix%, expiretime: %session_memcached_expire% }]
```

My biggest Question so far is : **How do you start a session ?**

Normally, you would have `$session = new Session();`
but not for handlers, since the documentation states (code converted to `Memcached`):

```
$storage = new NativeSessionStorage(array(), new MemcachedSessionHandler());
$session = new Session($storage);
```

and this is some really weird, because the constructor needs a `Memcached` instance for argument, which is not given in the example of the official [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/session_configuration.html)

What I did was to get the instance from the service running :

```
$memcached = $this->get('session.memcached');
$storage = new NativeSessionStorage(array(), new MemcachedSessionHandler($memcached));
$session = new Session($storage);
```

This didn't throw any exception but then again, so I filled the session with data:

```
$session->set('userName', $name);
$session->set('userfName', $fname);
$session->set('userPass', $pass);
$session->set('userId', $userId);
$session->set('userPost', $userPost);
$session->set('userImage', $userImage);
$session->set('logged', true);
```

Everything is perfect? Wait for it...I go on another controller and run the following:

```
$session = $this->get('session');
var_dump($session->get('userId')); // returns null
```

This means that either the session was not persisted (`Memcached` log says otherwise) or I don't do it right, which leads to my second question: **How do I read sessions from the Memcached Server?**

Please, I really need this to work because I need them in websockets project.

Following the comments this is what I did:

`app/config/config.yml`:

```
session:
    cookie_lifetime: 43200
    # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
    handler_id:  session
    save_path: ~
```

`app/config/services.yml`:

```
services:
    session.memcached:
        class: Memcached
        arguments:
            persistent_id: %session_memcached_prefix%
        calls:
            - [ addServer, [ %session_memcached_host%, %session_memcached_port% ]]

session:
    class:     Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\MemcachedSessionHandler
    arguments: [@session.memcached, { prefix: %session_memcached_prefix%, expiretime: %session_memcached_expire% }]
```

The error I get:

> PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::setSession() must implement interface Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface, instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\MemcachedSessionHandler given

Comment: `$session = $this->get('session');` =/= `$memcached = $this->get('session.memcached');` - better configure your session service as session (not as session.memcached), then you don't run into such mistakes.

Comment: the first command gets the Session instance , the second gets the Memcached instance , I don't get your comment right .. can you explain ?

Comment: Configure the session service to already use the memcached session. Then you only need to use `$session = $this->get('session')` (or better use parameter injection) and you do not need to care about whether it's memcached, on disk or stored engraved into stones on the moon.

Comment: You're funny , I like you :D
but help here "Configure the session service" what do you mean ?

Comment: When you write `$this->get('session')` you're accessing an object that has been configured as *"session service"*. It is configured in the service configuration for the entry *"session"*. See [Service Container](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html)

Comment: Back to you .. It's really frustrating but I didn't manage to get it work , the only session block in my conf file is the framework session 
I tried to modify it but I realized I was just doing random stuff , could you please detail the answer ?

Comment: This is hard to details while not having the same setup at hand. Just imagine you have got some configuration in your application in which you write down the "code" how to create the session object (that is comparable to the three `new`s you do for setting up the memcached session). However it's not PHP code but written in yml or xml. Sf2 takes care to turn that yml / xml into the actual PHP sequence to create the new memcached session instance when you call `$this->get('session')` then. It's just that you need to configure it properly (it's hard at the beginning, but once it works it's snap)

Comment: I need to copare tomorrow against my session configuration with the SF2 app I maintain. I then might be more helpful. I think you need provide an object with SessionInterface for the session. Memcached is the handler / session store, so it's a parameter to that then.

Comment: I'll be waiting @hakre

Comment: You're trying to make things more complex than they are. There's no need of creating all those objects if you're using the full stack framework. Session is started automatically too. Start with reading how you should be using sessions in Symfony Standard edition: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#managing-the-session Start simple, make sure it works with regular sessions. Thank move to configuring handlers. It's possible to configure memcached in php.ini with Symfony's native session handler.

Comment: Jakub, I was already working with sessions and I need to configure them for Memcached to work with Websockets. 
this said, do you have any working example ? because neither the docs , nor any blog is giving a code example .

Comment: The mistake was you either use services from the framework or manually  create those objects with `new`, but not both at the same time. Certainly objects created different ways don't share the contents.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Symfony full stack framework**

If you use the full stack Symfony framework, than configuring memcached as a session handler is as simple as specifying it in your php.ini:

```
session.save_handler=memcached
session.save_path=localhost:11211
```

Make sure that the `handler_id` is set to null (`~`) in your `app/config/config.yml`. This way Symfony will use the native php handler:

```
framework:
    session:
        # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
        handler_id:  ~
```

Now you can start using your session. It is going to be stored in memcached.

**Accessing the session**

Session can be accessed from the `Request` object:

```php
$request->getSession()->set('name', 'Kuba');
```

**HttpFoundation component**

The same can be set up outside of a full stack framework with the HttpFoundation component alone:

```php
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Attribute\NamespacedAttributeBag;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\NativeSessionStorage;

$storage = new NativeSessionStorage(array());
$session = new Session($storage, new NamespacedAttributeBag());

$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$request->setSession($session);
```

The above snippet sets the session up just like the full stack framework does (by default). This way, the script you'll put this code in, will share the session with a full Symfony application.

Comment: So It wasn't a good thing to use the services , right ? 
Thanks man and sorry for all the bother I caused on github

Comment: Symfony Framework also allows to configure memcached sessions without changing php.ini.

Comment: @JakubZalas: Thank you for `Make sure that the handler_id is set to null (~) in your app/config/config.yml`. It helped me a lot with signing in problem (worked on the second time... always). Now it works as it should :)

Answer (score 2):

There is a nice [gist](https://gist.github.com/K-Phoen/4327229) that will help you to start using MemcachedSessionHandler in your Symfony 2 project.